# how to plot on categorical columns based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I find it hard to plot the data based on conditions. For example,

df :

```
A   B   C   D
1   yes no  no 
2   no  no  no 
3   yes no  no 
4   no  no  yes
5   yes yes yes
6   yes yes no
7   no  yes no
```

I want to plot the data to see the count of all the "yes" in every column.

code :

```
df['B'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar')
```

This will kind of give me only one column but both the yes and nos. 
I want it for all the columns in x-axis representing the count of "yes" and count in y-axis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to have a count of how many `Yes` there are per column, check for equality and `sum` the boolean series:

```
df.loc[:,'B':].eq('yes').sum().plot.bar()
```

[image]

The same could be done using seaborn with:

```
sns.barplot(x='index',
            y='counts'  , 
            data=df.loc[:,'B':].eq('yes').sum().reset_index(name='counts'))
```

[image]

Comment: I dont want the column A ..how do I remove that

Comment: Well why is it there in the first place. Is it not the index @pylearner ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. See if the update does what you want @pylearner

Comment: yea, thats looks perfect. Thanks @yatu